# How can i define arguments for nested fields on server side using grapqhl?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm

How can I define arguments for nested fields? Suppose I want to consult all my posts but limit and sort the comments. Thank you for your help.

```
{
  allPosts {
    title,
    comments(limit: 5) {
      content
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to, is often designated as `Pagination`, and is something that is covered by the [GraphQL's specification](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/).

There are different possible ways of constructing the query to allow retrieving multiple records of a certain object type (comments in our situation).

The simplest option, can be achieved by defining the `GraphQL`'s query string with the object type you want to transverse in the plural form, meaning that your query would look like this:

```
{
  allPosts {
    title,
    comments {
      content
    }
  }
}
```

But with this implementation you would end up fetching all the data instead of simply retrieving a chunk of it. Obviously this approach can have many drawbacks depending on the volume of the data that is being fetched and should only be used on specific situations.

The easiest approach to achieve what you want is to request the comments as a "slice", meaning that you would be requesting a specific initial portion of the data set.

In this case, you would be requesting the initial 5 comments.

```
{
  allPosts {
    title,
    comments(first: 5) {
      content
    }
  }
}
```

But what if you want to paginate through the rest of the list?

```
{
   allPosts {
     title,
     comments(first: 5, offset:5) {
       content
     }
   }
 }
```

Doing this, you could ask for the following next 5 comments.

But the approach that is recommend to use when implementing Pagination is the **cursor-based pagination**, which would translate to something like this:

```
{
  allPosts {
    title,
    comments(first: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
         content
        }
        cursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The hard part consists on implementing the `resolvers` functionality (is slightly easier with frameworks like Apollo).

Comment: Thank you, you've made me quite clear. But my main question is just how to implement the resolver in backend, using apollo....